# Most efficient way to include javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, pageload

Hey I had more of a conceptual than technical question. Is it better for pageload time to have one document ready function with the javascript for all pages included at the top of every webpage, or to have separate functions on every page with the script needed for only that page? The second makes more sense, but hey idk.

Comment: right now everything is in one big function, limited to things like slideshows and dropdown menus, nothing fancy, but as I add more script the pages seem to be taking a bit longer to load each time. im not sure if my local host is just finicky or it's the script itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't load all your scripts at once for every page. This will cause unnecessary load times and as a result the user will think your page is loading slow.

Only load the scripts required for each page on a per page basis. Any time a script is encountered it will be cached, so they will all slowly be worked in if found instead of just one batch load all at once.

Comment: ooh good to know they're cached, ty! it says i have to wait a few minutes to accept this answer, but it answered my question perfectly :D